# ODATA to query arbitrary single 2-D table without knowing # of columns or their names in advance

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm engaged in an exercise in which I seem to have thinkers block.

I would like to create and expose an ODATA service (query only) that can be applied to any two dimensional single table and allow the consumer to query that table, without the program knowing in advance anything about the schema of the table.

Ideally I would like to use WCF Data Services.

One way to think of it -- the ODATA service is pointed to a file location where there might be a random (but valid) CSV file, and when pointed at that file, the consumer should be able to query and use the ODATA language to filter, sort, group, etc.

There are no joins.  It is a SINGLE table.

Another way of thinking about it is that it is a completely unknown-until-runtime DataTable.  (Note *not* a DataSet.  Just a single DataTable.)

Presumably the primary key is a constructed column Row Number, since there is nothing to guarantee uniqueness of any other column.

This seems like it should be easy, but every time I try a new strategy, I seem to run into a wall.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Using WCF Data Services for this use case will easily create a statically defined ODATA endpoint for a pre-existing entity model, in much the same way that a regular WCF service exposes a specific service interface that you define as the producer. To be clear, this is schema which is defined at compile time, not at runtime.

If you want to do more than this, chances are you need to write your own custom provider, the various ways to do so will give you progressively more powerful features at the expense of being successively trickier to implement. A good starting point is Alex James' excellent blog series which starts here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx

To be clear, implementing a custom provider is quite tricky, and may not be worth the effort depending on what your need is.

One way to get round this would be to implement a data service that exposes some kind of meta-model, key/value pairs, triple store etc etc, however that somewhat destroys the benefits of strong typing you get from using ODATA so I wouldn't especially recommend that approach either.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  This is a good link, and more helpful and complete than the one I was using, namely http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg191846.

I am find with writing my own custom provider, in fact that has been the focus of my exercise.  I expect that.  But even writing a custom provider, the "don't know the scheme until runtime" issue seems to be daunting.  Just not sure how to think about cracking the nut.

Comment: I'd suggest working through his examples and borrowing code from them as you need to get started. It's _only_ a case of implementing IDataServiceMetadataProvider and IQueryProvider and a few other things, then putting it all together! I wrote my own provider a year or so ago, starting mainly with this set of articles, so it's certainly not impossible if you have the time and inclination.

Answer (score 1):

for what it's worth, typeless entities are now supported in WebAPI 2.0 OData, see this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/leohu/archive/2013/11/05/typeless-entity-object-support-in-webapi.aspx